HowTo override default menus in 14.1 with an edited user copy of "MenuSetup.tr" (or similar method)?
With version 14.0 and older, I used to have custom color options added to the Format->TextColor menu using
$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/MenuSetup.tr
and
$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/MenuSetup.tr.
Apparently that method no longer works in 14.1.
Is there a new way to do this?
I used the suggestion of the answer to Mathematica ignores my custom MenuSetup.tr (Windows 10) by editing
$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/Components/Mathematica/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/MenuSetup.tr
That successfully modified the menu, but is not wholesome system administration.
Placing a modified copy of that file in
$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/Components/Mathematica/FrontEnd/TextResources/X/MenuSetup.tr
did not override the default configuration as did the similar method used with older versions of Mathematica.  Can the FrontEnd menu be modified in user space?  If so, how is that accomplished? Can (should) it be scripted in init.m?

It may be because 14.1 changed the directory.  They are now using a new all in one Wolfram App.  Try evaluating $UserBaseDirectory.  Notice that Instead of the Mathematica directory, it is now Wolfram.  I think if you copy in your old files into the new directory Wolfram Dictory in the appropriate place it should work.  I'm no expert, but I did have a similar problem and this fixed it for me.

The .Wolfram is in $UserBaseDirectory.
